# Eclipse compareEditor showing change line by line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using the following code to show the difference between two input in String format

```
protected Object prepareInput(IProgressMonitor monitor)
        throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {

    CompareItem left = new CompareItem(text1);
    CompareItem right = new CompareItem(text2);
    diffNode= new DiffNode(left, right);
    return diffNode;        
}
```

For input like

```
line1          testline
line2          line1
line3          line2
               line3
```

it's showing all lines are different, instead of showing only first line is different.

The way I am calling compare editor is by

```
CompareUI.openCompareDialog(new MyCompare(configuration, ((MyEditor) 
    editorPart).originalText(), ((MyEditor) editorPart).currentConverted()) );
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
CompareConfiguration configuration = new CompareConfiguration();
CompareUI.openCompareDialog(new CompareEditorInput(configuration) {
    @Override
    protected Object prepareInput(final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        String text1 = "line1\nline2\nline3\n";
        String text2 = "testline\nline1\nline2\nline3\n";

        CompareItem left = new CompareItem("1", text1);
        CompareItem right = new CompareItem("2", text2);
        DiffNode diffNode = new DiffNode(left, right);
        return diffNode;
    }
});
```

Works perfectly for me on Kepler.

[image: Result on Kepler]

So I thinks you're not giving us enough data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should notice this parameter "Differencer.CHANGE"

```
CompareEditorInput input = new CompareEditorInput(config) { 
    StringCompareItem left = new StringCompareItem("left", leftContent);
    StringCompareItem right = new StringCompareItem("right", rightContent);

    @Override
    protected Object prepareInput(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        return new DiffNode(null, Differencer.CHANGE, null, left, right);
    }

};
```